# Should mySQL INSERT be done in constructor?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am starting to build a new project in `PHP` using OOP, and I have a dilemma about Object-Database relations.

For example, I have a User object. Should the constructor function already do the `INSERT INTO... ?` so I will call `$user = new User($user_data);`

Or should I have a different `$user->save()` method to do the `INSERT`?

Comment: That depends what the User class is supposed to do. Is it just to insert new users? What about an existing user, will you create another class to be able to retrieve its data?

Comment: What happens if you want to load an existing user and modify some fields?

Comment: you should use different method to save user. because Constructor should only do Initialization not other as per OOPs...

Comment: Read the data-source architecture section under http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Having a constructor perform an insert query doesn't sound like a good idea, IMHO. The `User` class, I think, should be regarded as a model, an object that collects data, which can be sent to a service layer. That's where the actual `insert` can be performed.

Just treat the `User` class as a type. Suppose an existing user logs in:

```
$login = new User(array('username' => $_POST['username'],
                        'pass' => $_POST['passwd']));
```

Then, inside the `User` class:

```
class User
{
    const SALT = 'fo0bar';
    private $_hash = null;
    private $_name = null;

    public function __construct (array $request, $login = false)
    {
        //this isn't the best hash in the world, of course...
        $this->_hash = sha1($request['username'].SALT.$request['pass']);
        $this->_name = $request['username'];
    }
    public function getHash()
    {
        return $this->_hash;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}
```

Nothing more than that, as far as the constructor goes. Just add more data if required, and some getters and setters. This object can then be passed to an object that has all db methods and holds the connection(s) you need, it can build a query using the hash and name getters, check if the user exists and perform an `INSERT` query if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use a separate 'method' for creating / saving a user.
The constructor will be executed every time you instantiate a User i.e use "user = new User()".
If inserted into your constructor a new user will be attempted to be created whenever a User object is created, which may well not be needed for the purpose you intend.

Answer (score 0):

- Sometimes you may need to create an empty instance
- php doesn't support overloading: Overloading would allow you to create a constructor which creates and empty instance.
- You wouldn't want to insert an empty record for each object instance.

So I don't recommend adding an insert query to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a separate save() function in your class for the following reasons

- You have the opportunity to manipulate/amend object data before it is saved
- When retrieving data, you will no doubt call `$user->getAll()`. So when initialising your user object, in this case - we don't want to be storing any data.

Try doing something like this

```
protected $_data;

public function __construct(array $data) {
    $this->_data = $data;
}

public function save() {
    //TODO: Save $data 

    return $this;
}

public function getAll() {
    //TODO: Get from database and populate $this->_data

    return $this->_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way of doing this is to separate model, and mapper. This means that User is an empty data store (model) - and you have a mapper which interacts with the object. Typical CRUD operations:

```
<?php
$model = new User();
$model->setName('Name');

$mapper->create($model);

$user = $mapper->find('Name');

$user->setName('NewName');
$mapper->update($user);

$model->delete($user);
```